# ASP.NET Web API microservices + Angular front end - how to manage auth cookie?

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, asp.net-core

Can anyone suggest what are the standard practices when it comes to Cookie Authentication (ASP.NET) and a separate (CORS) front-end using Angular.

The problem that I have is when I log in in my Web API using Postman/ Swagger - the Auth Cookie gets created. When I use Angular through localhost:4200, no cookie is created.

For angular post method Http headers configuration I use `{withCredentials: true}`
and these are my configurations for the cookie plus CORS for the API:
1 - Middleware

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
     builder
  .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .AllowCredentials()
  .AllowAnyMethod());

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers()
             .RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

2 - registering the CORS services:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                          policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                          policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                          policy.AllowCredentials();
                      });
});
```

3 - Cookie configuration:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
{
    config.Cookie.Name = "Identity.Cookie";
    config.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
    config.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
    config.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;

    config.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    config.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
```

Some users reported that no cookie should be created in the client browser when using Localhost:4200, for example I've read this opinion but cannot understand what it means, exactly:
"Subsequent requests will be sent by the browser and the browser will automatically bring the cookies."
Maybe, I should only assign a simple variable which checks if the response of the login is 200 Okay and then use it as a confirmation, later in the code?

So, can anyone advise what is the standard practice, to authenticate my front-end?

Comment: The ASP.NET Core documentation addresses this in [Authentication and authorization for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0). The article uses JWT Bearer tokens, which are supported by ASP.NET Core itself

Comment: So you mean that the Bearer tokens, not Cookies are the standard practice when it comes to Authenticating in Angular?

Comment: your API should not be relying on cookies. you should use bearer token for API authentication.

Comment: Thank you. I shall refactor my code, accordingly.

Comment: I made small changes to my cookie configuration and I can confirm that my Cookie Auth process is working for my Angular Application running on Http.
So - Cookie Authentication is possible between Asp.Net and Angular.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I updated my Cookie and CORS configuration.
Also, currently, my Angular Front End is using http, but in future versions I shall fix it with https.

So for now, I can **confirm** that **this configuration is working**.
Whenever I login from my Angular Application successfully - a cookie is created in it. **This cookie then is also successfully read by the backend**, thus completing the security process, required by the backend!

I hope I helped someone reading this topic. And don't forget to add

```
{withCredentials : true}
```

in the headers of each HttpRequest made from your Angular application.